# How can I setup webdriver to wait after each command?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Is webdriver have any methods to setup timeout after each command? It's creepy to write time.sleep(n) after each command.... Any suggestions?

Comment: There is a similar question - [Python WebDriver wait](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917785/python-webdriver-wait)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `WebDriverWait` or `WebDriverWait.until`.  The docs [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html?highlight=webdriverwait#selenium.webdriver.support.wait.WebDriverWait) have a full description of how they work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using this

```
protected void sleep(int i) {
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(i, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

sleep(1);
```

the driver sleeps 1 seconde before he goes on.

i don't know if it's exactly what you want.